# Pegar a largura de uma imagem em VUE/JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

nesse código abaixo ao selecionar uma imagem gera uma pre-vizualizacao,
eu consigo por exemplo pegar o type da imagem, mas não consigo pegar a largura, existe alguma forma de obter o width e height do arquivo?

```
  <input type="file" id="file" ref="myFiles" class="custom-file-input" name="logo_login" 
                                  @change="previewFiles_logo_login">

previewFiles_logo_login(e) {

                    const file = e.target.files[0];

                    alert(file.clientWidth);

                    if(!this.arquivos_permitidos.includes(file.type)){

                      this.msg_img_logo = true;


                      return;
                    }


                    this.logo_login = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar a largura e altura das imagens com os métodos **Javascript**: `naturalWidth()` e `naturalHeight` que retornam os valores originais da imagem.

```
previewFiles_logo_login(e) {

   const file = e.target.files[0];

   const larg = file.naturalWidth;               // pega a largura do arquivo em file
   const altu = file.naturalHeight;              // pega a altura do arquivo em file

   alert(`Largura ${larg} - Altura ${altu}`);

   if(!this.arquivos_permitidos.includes(file.type)){

     this.msg_img_logo = true;

     return;
   }


   this.logo_login = URL.createObjectURL(file);

},
```